# Displaying the day on the calendar from the textbox generated

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, calendar, datepicker

may i ask on how to display the day (Monday, tuesday,etc) from the textbox which had a datepicker javascript, into the textbox which would echo the day from the datepicker.

example: textbox1(datepicker, when the user selects september 12 2013, it would echo Thursday to textbox2) textbox2 = Thursday. Thank you.

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: i don't have yet the code, amal, but your help would be very great. thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Simple code here:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="date" >
<input type="text" id="tellMeDay" >
```

jQuery:

```
$(function () { 
 $( "#date" ).datepicker({ 
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        var date = $( "#date" ).datepicker( "getDate" );
         $("#tellMeDay").val($.datepicker.formatDate('DD', date));
    }
 });
});
```

Here a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UuE82/)

Answer (score 0):

You can have a JS piece watch that text input, and when there's a change, you can `.getDay()` it. With that, you can do a switch/case or an if/then/else/elseif or whatever your logic method of choice is. The details of `.getDay()` can be found at http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getday.asp

Answer (score 0):

How about to use some JQuery Ui? http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/
Or try to use in HTML attribute type="date" like `<input type="date" />` in Html5
Or just google it! Datapicker day name display